# creating menu items with children (sub items)

Tags: routes, navigation

i want to have a menu option called Info in my 'main menu', which has children of Policies and Contact. how can i set it up so that when a user clicks on Info, it just shows the child options in the drop down underneath Info and doesnt display a node? I only seem to be able to achieve what I want by setting up a blank dummy node which Info is linked to. I'm using Superfish, but i dont think thats relevant.

Answer (score 0):

How about installing [Menu attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes). See if it's nofollow option works. If not, still use it by setting a class of 'no-follow' on this particular menu-item. Then add some jQuery to you pages wherein you target the anchor tag related to this class for its click event and disable the default action. I don't think there should be a conflict as Superfish opens up menus on hover, I think? But try. And also set up the menu so that it points to the first child so that Drupal menu UI will accept.

[How to Disable/Inactivate Some of the Non-Leaf Menu-Items (but keep their children visible and enabled/active)](http://www.drupalgardens.com/content/how-disableinactivate-some-non-leaf-menu-items-keep-their-children-visible-and-enabledactive)